# TiVo videos on a Mac?

Tags: mac

Has anyone found a good way to view TiVo Premiere videos on a Mac (late 2012 mini, El Cap)? TiVo Transfer for Mac worked fine for years, but now only downloads partial files and has been abandoned by Roxio. I can't make cTiVo download complete files either - it calls it "Complete" after transferring 25 MB of a 1.6 GB video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you post your ctivo issue over on Github? The other place to look for options is tivocommunity.com

Comment: Yes I just did.